# Laravel lazy collection for huge data

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am querying a large data sets from the table and then iterating through a loop for creating a json file.

```
$user = App\User::all();

foreach($user as $val){
  // logic goes here for creating the json file
}
```

Now the problem i am facing is that when iterating through the loop it is consuming memory and i am getting error 'Allowed memory size exhausted'.And also the cpu usage of the server becomng so high.
My question how i should use the laravel lazy collections to get rid of this issue.I have gone through the offcial docs but couldnt find the way.

Comment: what are you doing with the data inside your `foreach` loop?  and you can't find the way to do what?

Comment: i am creating a new array based on certain conditions and later that array is converted to json

Comment: as you keep adding to this array it will use more and more memory ... and what can't you find the way to do in the docs?

Comment: i dont understand how to use the lazy collection of laravel and create the array based on the condition

Comment: create the array based on what condition? ... the 3rd code block https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#lazy-collections shows how to get a lazy collection from the query; you don't need the `filter` call (as that is just an example)  "However, the query builder's `cursor` method returns a LazyCollection instance."

Comment: condition means if and else..on which some flags are changed ...my query is returning the data very fast but i my problem is with the foreach loop and i want to get rid of it

Comment: if you need to iterate the data you need to iterate the data, you don't just get rid of it ... in the docs it gets the lazy collection from the `cursor` method then it iterates it with a `foreach` loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202697/discussion-between-samim-and-lagbox).

Answer (score 8):

Just replace the `all` method with the `cursor` one.

```php
$user = App\User::cursor();

foreach($user as $val){
  // logic goes here for creating the json file
}
```

For more informations about the methods you can chain, refer to the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#lazy-collection-introduction)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle big/large/huge [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections)/array/data with Laravel you have to use `LazyCollection` class ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#lazy-collections)) with `chunk()` method ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-chunk)).

**Using chunks is necessary** because if your script will fails in a middle of your large array - script job will cancel everything with error, in case of chunks some of job will be handled. And `LazyCollection` provides a **low memory usage**. So to get a maximum of profit the best way is to use the ones together.

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\LazyCollection;

//$bigArray - an array with large data

$chunkSize = 100;
$lazy = collect($bigArray)->lazy();
// or MyModel::lazy($chunkSize)->..., NOT MyModel::all()->lazy()
$lazy->chunk($chunkSize)
->each(function (LazyCollection $items) {
    $items->each(function ($item) {
        //do your job here with $item
    })
});
```

This **method does not guarantee** a complete solution of the problem like `504 Gateway Time-out` or memory leaking. So try to increase `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` with `fastcgi_read_timeout` if you use Nginx web server. You can solve this error [via Laravel and Nginx settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76696840/724816)